# I am getting two errors in my socket.io when I am connecting it to my client side Javascript

Tags: socket.io

I am getting two errors:

1. connection refused
2. `io` is not defined.

```js
const io = require("socket.io")(8000);
```

This is how I expose Socket.io for JavaScript:

```html
<script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

On my client-side JavaScript, I inserted Socket.io.

```js
const socket = io('http://localhost:8000');
```

I tried even this way.

```js
const socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8000/');
```

But the problem was still there.

This is my server side code.

```js
const io = require('socket.io')(8000);
const users = {};
io.on('connection',socket=>{
    socket.on('new-user-joined',name=>{
        users[socket.id] = name;
        socket.broadcast.emit('user-joined',name)
    })
    socket.on('send',message=>{
        socket.broadcast.emit('recieve',message:message,name:users[socket.id]})
    })
})
socket.on('disconnect',()=>{
    socket.broadcast.emit('left',users[socket.id])
    delete users[socket.id]
})
```

I even changed my port number `8080` but this also not helped me. I switched back to port `8000`. I was not getting any solution.I left those errors and start writing my script and after some time those errors was gone I don't know how? After some time I faced that errors again. And again after some time those errors was gone and this happens to me for 3 to 4 times.

Comment: Can you also share the server-side code?

Answer (score 0):

For `io is not defined issue`,
Add this below CDNs :

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.0.0.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Keeping the localhost link below is a better choice.

and

`socket.on('disconnect'` event should be inside the **io.on('connection'** event.